# Jasmine test a promise.then function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I try to test my app with Jasmine and got the following problem:
I will calculate something in the `then` function of my promise. That's the point where I need to test my code.

Here is the code of my controller:

```
  TestCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "TestService"];
  /* ngInject */
  function TestCtrl($scope, TestService) {
    $scope.loadData = function () {
      TestService.getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.data;
        $scope.filtered = $scope.data.filter(function(item){
          if(item.id > 1000){
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        })
      });
    }
  }
```

And my Jasmine test code:

```
describe('TestService tests', function () {
  var $q;
  beforeEach(function () {
    module('pilot.fw.user');
  });
  beforeEach(inject(function (_$q_) {
    $q = _$q_;
  }));
  describe('UserController Tests', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, $controller) {
      this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
      this.$rootscope = $rootScope;
      this.$httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
      this.scope = $rootScope.$new();
      var TestServiceMock = {
        getData: function () {
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          var result = [{
            "id": 1720,
            "user": 1132
          },
            {
              "id": 720,
              "user": 132
            }, {
              "id": 1721,
              "user": 1132
            }];
          deferred.promise.data = result;
          deferred.resolve(result);
          return deferred.promise;
        }
      };
      this.controller = $controller('TestCtrl', {
        '$scope': this.scope,
        'TestService': TestServiceMock
      });
    }));

    it('test', function(){
      this.scope.loadData();
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    })
  });
});
```

The strange thing I don't understand is (tested with console logs):

- My promise is created and returned
- My loadData function is called and it will call the getData() function from the TestService
- Everything inside the then function won't be executed although I return the promise as resolved

So how could I test the code inside the ***then*** function?
Thanks for help

Answer (score 58):

the jasmine 'it' method takes a done parameter that you can call for async testing

```
it('Should be async', function(done) {
  someAsyncFunction().then(function(result) {
    expect(result).toBe(true);
    done();
  });
});
```

Feel free to go as deep as you want, just be sure to call done when EVERYTHING is finished. Jasmine's default timeout is 5 seconds per test, so if the async stuff isn't done by then jasmine will crash. You can change this setting in the configs or set it in the terminal.

This is straight from the jasmine docs, showing you how to handle the default timeout interval

```
describe("long asynchronous specs", function() {
  var originalTimeout;
  beforeEach(function() {
    originalTimeout = jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL;
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
  });

  it("takes a long time", function(done) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      done();
    }, 9000);
  });

  afterEach(function() {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = originalTimeout;
  });
});
```

I think that if it doesn't work in 10 seconds, you may have faulty methods. ESPECIALLY if you are talking to a local server / db. This stuff should only take this long if you are performing HEAVY computations, or are hitting an external api with a not-so-great internet connection. If everything is local (or stubbed / mocked!) then anything over 5-10 seconds is a definite red flag.

Comment: it('test', function(done){
      TestServiceMock.getData().then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
      });
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      done();
    })  
I tried it this way but my console log isn´t even called ...
Same problem as before :/
- Sorry for CodeStyle -    
Tanks for your help

Comment: You're calling done OUTSIDE of the 'then'!
Make sure that 'done' is INSIDE of your then methods :)

Comment: Otherwise, you're executing before the promise has even resolved, much less know what it's result was. Notice how in my example, I pass the result of the promise into the expect method? That only works when it's resolved, which is inside of 'then'

Comment: But then I get this errorCode: Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Comment: That refers to the bit I mentioned about jasmine's default timeout. :)

Comment: How are you executing the tests? In a terminal, gulp / grunt task, browser standalone, etc... ?

Comment: @JonasHans I updated the answer to shed some light on the timeout

Comment: okay but when I set the default timeout to 30000 e.g. I get the same error after 30 sec :D  I´m executing it with in the browser but I can test it with gulp too

Comment: Does this function work outside of the tests? Sounds like a faulty method to me

Comment: Actually that won't work, because your controller's loadData method doesn't return anything. Try returning the call to the TestService on line 5. That should return a promise a chain.

Comment: Just add a simple 'return' statement before the                     

TestService.getData().then(function (response) {
                               
line in your controller

Comment: Yeah outside my testing environment it works fine ... But when I execute the TestService.getData().then in the test, the hole then function will not called !!! ( tested it with a console.log instant after the function(response){console.log(response)}

Comment: Haha, I'm going to sound like a broken record. The 'return' statement is CLUTCH with promises. When you return the TestService, you return a promise. This let's you call then. But the 'result' of that 'then', is what you return INSIDE of the TestService call. You just modify the scope

Comment: So you either need to return the result, like the 'responseText', or you can disregard the 'result' argument entirely, since by the time the 'then' is called, your scope has already been modified. So you can test your scope instead of the result.

Comment: For the most part $q is A+ compliant. Check out the spec to get a better idea of how to use promises, and chain them, compose them, etc...

Comment: The idea is that you first return a promise, this gives you a then method. Whatever you return from the 'then' will be the 'result' argument of the NEXT then method. You keep getting nothing because none of your promises / methods return anything.

Comment: Thanks again ! But i still can´t get it. I understand you in the following that I should add a return statement to the then function of the promise ... but when I edit my method in the following way it still wount work:      
$scope.loadData = function () {
      TestService.getData().then(function (response) {
        console.log("test");
        $scope.data = response.data;
        $scope.filtered = $scope.data.filter(function(item){
          if(item.id > 1000){
            return true;
          }
          return false;
        });
        return "Tanks for help";
      });

Comment: And when I console.log($scope.data) after the then ... $scope.data is still undefined

Comment: Ok Just added a new answer, let me know how that works for you?

Comment: This is fine, but I'd suggest using jasmine-promises so that you can return your promises from the spec and get free error handling: 

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-promises

Answer (score 10):

You better watch this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/unit-testing/asynchronous/

You have actually 3 ways:

1) use regular it:

```
it('test', (done) => {
   const spy = spyOn(func, 'bar').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
   spy.calls.mostRecent().returnValue.then(res => {
      ...your expect here...
      done();
   })
} );
```

2) use async in beforeEach and it:

```
it('test', async(() => {
    spyOn(func, 'bar').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
    fixture.whenStable().then(res => {
       ...your expect here...
    })
 } ));
```

3) use fakeAsync if you don't have Http or XHR calls:

```
it('test', fakeAsync(() => {
    spyOn(func, 'bar').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(true));
    tick();
    ...your expect here...
 } ));
```

Answer (score 6):

hope this solution helps. One approach I've found useful when testing is mocking dependencies. I've tried to comment out what I've done as much as possible.

```
var returnMock, $scope, TestServiceMock, controller;

beforeEach(module('app'));

beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
    returnMock = {
        then: jasmine.createSpy(),
    };
    $scope = {};
    // first assumption is You are testing TestService extensively,
    // I don't care about what getData has to do to get results
    // All I care about is it gets called when I call loadData
    TestServiceMock = {
        getData: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(returnMock);
    };

    controller = $controller;
}));

it('should load data when loadData function is called and result set is 
under 1000', function() {
    controller('TestCtrl', {
        $scope,
        TestServiceMock
    });
    // another assumption is your data comes back in such a format
    // perhaps in the actual code check whether data exists and proceed
    // or do some other action
    var returnedData = {
        data: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'item 1',
            },
        ]
    }
    // when I execute the function/method
    $scope.loadData();
    // I expect getData to be called
    expect(TestServiceMock.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // I expect then to be called and the reason is I mocked it
    expect(returnMock.then).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
    returnMock.then.calls.mostRecent().args[0](returnedData);
    // expect data on scope to be equal to my mocked data
    expect($scope.data).toEqual(returnedData.data);
    // don't expect any result because 1 < 1000
    expect($scope.filtered).toEqual([]);
    expect($scope.filtered.length).toEqual(0);
});

it('should load data when loadData function is called and result set is over 1000', 
     function() {
    controller('TestCtrl', {
        $scope,
        TestServiceMock
    });
    var returnedData = {
        data: [
            {
                id: 1,
                name: 'item 1',
            },
            {
                id: 1000,
                name: 'item 1000',
            },
            {
                id: 1001,
                name: 'item 1000',
            },
            {
                id: 1002,
                name: 'item 1002',
            }
        ]
    }
    $scope.loadData();
    expect(TestServiceMock.getData).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(returnMock.then).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
    returnMock.then.calls.mostRecent().args[0](returnedData);
    expect($scope.data).toEqual(returnedData.data);
    // expect a result because some entries in the mocked data have id > 1000
    expect($scope.filtered).toEqual([
        {
            id: 1001,
            name: 'item 1000',
        },
        {
            id: 1002,
            name: 'item 1002',
        }]);
    expect($scope.filtered.length).toEqual(2);
});
```

[Official Jasmine Docs](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-29) explain most of the concepts extensively. Hope the solution helps!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Let me tell ya what I do, for Angular 1.x and 2.x+ projects.  Use the angular testing tools to get rid of callbacks/nests in your async tests.  In angular 1.x, that means using a combination of $q and $rootScope.$apply().  In angular 2.x+, that means using something like fakeAsync.

[From the Angular 1.x docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing)

```
it('should simulate promise', inject(function($q, $rootScope) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var promise = deferred.promise;
  var resolvedValue;

  promise.then(function(value) { resolvedValue = value; });
  expect(resolvedValue).toBeUndefined();

  // Simulate resolving of promise
  deferred.resolve(123);
  // Note that the 'then' function does not get called synchronously.
  // This is because we want the promise API to always be async, whether or not
  // it got called synchronously or asynchronously.
  expect(resolvedValue).toBeUndefined();

  // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(resolvedValue).toEqual(123);
}));
```

The disadvantage is that your code is tied to angular, the advantages are that your code is flat and it's portable to 2.x+!

I was a fan of the mocha test runner that allowed me to return promises in my tests, you could try to get that going, but there are downsides to that as well like needing to modify your code specifically for a test.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your controller, you should 'return' values like so.

```
TestCtrl.$inject = ["$scope", "TestService"];
/* ngInject */
function TestCtrl($scope, TestService) {
  $scope.loadData = function () {
    // Return this call, since it will return a new promise
    // This is what let's you do $scope.loadData.then()
    return TestService.getData().then(function (response) {
      // What you return in here will be the first argument
      // of your then method, in the tests / any env
      // Ex. return 'foo'
      // will result in .then(result => result === 'foo') //=> true
      // return one of these, i suggest the data, go SRP!
      return $scope.data = response.data;

      // I would do this stuff in a separate function, but you
      // can return 'filtered' instead if you like.
      //
      // $scope.filtered = $scope.data.filter(function(item){
      //   if(item.id > 1000){
      //     return true;
      //   }
      //   return false;
      // });
    });
  }
}
```

Remember that calling something AFTER 'then' doesn't mean anything, values must be called INSIDE 'then'. Not after it, or before it. But inside it. Like Tom Green and that poor moose in Freddy Got Fingered.

Comment: Rough, I wanna upvote for the FGF reference, but I don't think controllers should return anything unless they are returning something for the view